# How to get two collection views to show up properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a collection view for messages in my view controller (JSQMessagesVIewController), and I have another collection view for the navigation bar. I've tried to implement this two different ways so they both show up, but it seems like no matter how I go about setting it up, it has to be one or the other - there's no scenario where both collection views can appear simultaneously.

Here are the two different approaches:

1. Add `if/else` statements in the collection view methods. For example:

   ```
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   if collectionView == navBarCollectionView {
       return avatarDictionary.count
   } else {
       return messages.count
   }
   }
   ```
2. Put the collection view methods & all code for the navigation bar collection in a separate class, then add it to the chat controller navigation bar from there.

However the first method results in ONLY the nav bar collection view showing up, the messages are hidden. If I take away the `if/else` statements, the messages reappear (although obviously at that point the nav bar collection doesn't show up).

Using the second method, the messages show up but the collection view doesn't.

Here's the code for setting up the navigation bar collection view:

```
let navBarCollectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(70), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(500), height: CGFloat(40)), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
    let layout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
    navBarCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    navBarCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    navBarCollectionView.register(NavBarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    navBarCollectionView.delegate = self
    navBarCollectionView.dataSource = self
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(40))
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(navBarCollectionView)
    navBarCollectionView.reloadData()
```

I can post more code if needed but if anyone can see what's going wrong here, can you let me know?

Comment: If both collection views have the same data source (It seems like the view controller is the data source for both), you can use the `collectionView` parameter to check just like you've done. Do you do this check in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`?

Comment: I do the check in all of the CV methods except for two: `messageDataForItemAt`, which is a JSQMessages-specific method and not applicable to the nav bar collection view, and `sizeForItemAt`, which is only for the nav bar collection view and not the messages. Here are all the methods: https://pastebin.com/3bSL879F

Comment: The thing I'm unsure about, and what might be causing problems, is the fact that the JSQMessages collection view is simply called `collectionView`, so I don't know if my check with `if collectionView == ......`, is confusing the program, thinking that I'm reassigning that variable or something? Here's what I mean: http://imgur.com/a/LxFeA

Comment: What's going on here??
 `let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell`
Why aren't you dequeueing a cell? What is the `super` class of this data source object?

Comment: That's how the messages collection view is setup I think, that much I didn't change from a tutorial I started this project off of - does it seem off?

Comment: What is the `super` class of this data source object?

Your collection view is a property of your view controller, right? So really it's name is `self.collectionView`. The compiler can usually figure out which one you mean. You can use syntax highlighting to distinguish which one the compiler is using. In the first code sample, `collectionView` is probably referring to the parameter.

Comment: Do you think there's any changes I can make to get both collection views to show up, or do you think the way JSQMessagesViewController is set up, it won't allow for two collection views? I'm not sure how to find out what's going on behind the `super.collectionView` line, but I can find out if it will help lead to a solution.

Comment: When you say a collection view does or doesn't "show up" ... what do you mean by that? Are the datasource and delegate methods being called twice, once for each collection view? Or only once? If twice, what are you seeing in debug to explain one or the other "not showing up"?

Comment: If I have the `if/else` checks in the methods, and the nav bar collection "shows up" by this I mean it is visible to the human eye on the screen, I can see in the debugger that the data for the messages collection view is there (i.e. printing `messages.count` shows me that there are 5 messages), but the messages collection view does now "show up", by that I mean it is not visible to the human eye on the screen.

Comment: ok... so, in debug, what are the properties of the "messages collection view"? Frame? isHidden? Scroll Offsets? If you jump into Debug Hierarchy, where is the "not visible" Collection View?

Comment: I'm not very good at reading the debugger, but if I place a breakpoint on `return messages[indexPath.item]`, and expand self->JSQMessagesViewController->collectionView there are tons of values there - I can take a closer look if you let me know what red flags I'm looking for - couldn't see "Frame" or "isHidden". Here's a pic of the debugger (http://imgur.com/a/zaShL), is it ok that `navBarCollectionView` seems to be within JSQMessages->collectionView?

Comment: This is what I meant by "Debug Hierarchy" - https://imgur.com/a/3kaIC

Comment: Ah ok, cool. So I did that and if I understand what I'm looking at, these are the two collections views: http://imgur.com/a/5SWq9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142541/discussion-between-donmag-and-kingtim).